# PHP Merge two sub array with in sub array

Tags: php, merge, addition

I have two array

```
$array1 = array( array('a1', 'a11'), array('b1', 'b11'), array('c1', 'c11'));
$array2 = array( array('a111'), array('b111'), array('c111'));
```

And my result array shout like the below

```
Array (
     0 = > array('a1', 'a11', 'a111'),
     1 = > array('b1', 'ba11', 'b111'),
     2 = > array('c1', 'c11', 'c111'),
)
```

Comment: And what have you tried to do it so far ?

Comment: Create a target array. Iterate over all elements of one of the source arrays (assuming they have the same length). For each index, push the combined result of the corresponding two sub-arrays (you can use `+` to combine them) into the target array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array1 = array( array('a1', 'a11'), array('b1', 'b11'), array('c1', 'c11'));
$array2 = array( array('a111'), array('b111'), array('c111'));

/*
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
  $result[] = array_merge($v, $array2[$k]);
}
*/

$result = array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: @nosper Thank you, 

I need something better then this.

Comment: In what way 'better' ?

Comment: it is better, If possible Without foreach loop

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: You could directly do array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2); No need for the anonymous function ^_^

Comment: @Kulvar you are right. Thx for fix :)

Comment: @Kulvar Thx, But which one is best in performance?

Comment: You mean foreach vs array_map? Measure and check and give us results too :)

Comment: If you want performance, there are three things that matter:
Improve your algorithm, use native functions instead of rewritting them, keep your code clear and understandable.

You'll always get a better executing performance by writing all your code without any function call, but if you want to improve/update your code, understand what each part do when you come back at it three months later, or work with other people... don't seek only executing performance.

For information, for a 1 000 000 loop test, the difference is that array_map() is on average 0.0000002 second longer than foreach.